# How to Authorize a Facebook Application to Read Public Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created a simple Facebook application just so I can read public events from one Facebook page via the OpenGraph API. At one point this was all working fine, but now the application no longer has permission to view the events: I just get back an empty "data" object in the JSON response, which matches what I get when I ask for events from any page. I do have a valid auth_token, etc as part of the request.

What is the easiest way to grant the application (which doesn't currently have a public face) permission to grab the events?